# Website is showing another website on non-existent website page

Tags: wordpress, apache, security

This is a peculiar one.

I work for an agency, and we develop WordPress and JAM Stack sites for our clients.

I have been contacted by the IT team for one of the clients (an NGO), and they flagged something that I have not seen before.

NOTE: I am going to be using `example.org` as the website, to protect the identity of the client.

Basically, we developed a WordPress site for them, which works great and all, but as it turn outs there is a page on the website which points to a totally different website

The example page is as follows

```
example.org/news/points-to-different-website/
```

The `news` page doesn't exist in anywhere on WordPress system, and neither does it exist as a custom post type.

And another thing, I noticed is when I removed the `/` at the end of the URL, it shows the custom `404` page developed for the website

```
example.org/news/points-to-different-website
```

But as soon as you add the `/`, it shows a totally different website.

I have checked all the `Apache` configuration files related to the site, and it is just the normal setup for any WordPress site.

So, I am wondering what could be causing this, and how can one prevent it?

Answer (score 0):

That's a strange issue. Does `example.org/news/points-to-different-website/` actually redirect to another full URL, i.e. `differentwebsite.com`, or is the different site actually at `example.org/news/points-to-different-website/`?

Try

1. emptying the trash for both pages and posts, as there could be a conflicting slug that is causing a redirect.
2. Reset permalinks.
3. Using PHPMyAdmin, search the database for the URL `points-to-different-website` and see if there is malware or some kind of a redirect, an iFrame, etc.

Comment: Yes, a different website is showing at `example.org/news/points-to-different-website/`

Comment: Did you check Apache virtual hosts?

Comment: Yes, I checked the virtual hosts

Comment: Ok, try the other three points I listed.

Comment: Can you go directly to that different website via that domain.com?

Answer (score 0):

This can sometimes happen if the server hostname is not set up correctly.

What can happen is website on the server will show in place of a non-existent site or page from another website on the same server.

If you are using a reseller hosting/shared hosting, then the site could be from another account on the server, the site could also be from another server, for example:

There are 2 servers with the hostnames `serverone.myserver.com` and `servertwo.myserver.com`...   A site on serverone might show in place of a site or page on servertwo.